# Linear Lie algebra generated by $\mathbb{R}$-diagonalizable matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, lie-algebras

If $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ denotes the Lie algebra of real $(n \times n)$-matrices, then the $\mathbb{R}$-diagonalizable matrices generate $\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ as a Lie algebra.

If $\mathfrak{g}<\mathfrak{gl}_n(\mathbb{R})$ is an arbitrary Lie subalgebra, then it need not be generated by the $\mathbb{R}$-diagonalizable matrices which it contains. In fact, $\mathfrak{g}$ might not contain any diagonalizable matrices (e.g. if it is generated by a single non-diagonalizable matrix).

What are criteria which guarantee that $\mathfrak{g}$ is generated by $\mathbb{R}$-diagonalizable matrices? In particular, is it sufficient for $\mathfrak{g}$ to be simple and non-compact?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes: if $K$ is a field of characteristic zero and $\mathfrak{g}$ is semisimple with no $K$-anisotropic factor (when $K=\mathbf{R}$, $K$-anisotropic means compact) then it is generated (and even linearly spanned) by its $K$-diagonalizable elements. And more generally if $\mathfrak{g}$ is perfect (trivial abelianization) with no compact factor.

Since $\mathfrak{g}$ is perfect, it is the Lie algebra of some algebraic subgroup of $\mathrm{GL}_n$.

The set of $K$-diagonalizable elements in $\mathfrak{g}$ is stable under scalar multiplication, and under the action of $G$. Hence its span is a $G$-invariant subspace of $\mathfrak{g}$, hence is an ideal $I$.

If by contradiction $I\neq \mathfrak{g}$, let $J$ be a maximal proper ideal of $\mathfrak{g}$ containing $I$. Hence $\mathfrak{g}/J$ is either 1-dimensional or simple. The first case is excluded since $\mathfrak{g}$ is perfect. In the second case, the quotient is $K$-isotropic by assumption. It is a split quotient (by standard structure theory), but then we have a simple $K$-isotropic subalgebra $\mathfrak{s}\subset\mathfrak{g}$ with no nontrivial $K$-diagonalizable element. This is a contradiction: indeed a maximal $K$-split abelian subalgebra of $\mathfrak{s}$ is positive-dimensional and consists of $K$-diagonalizable elements.

---

Addendum:

In the above setting, every element is a sum of $K$-diagonalizable elements. Hence   every element of $\mathfrak{g}$ is a sum of $m$ $K$-diagonalizable elements, for some $m$ (e.g., $m=\dim(\mathfrak{g})$ works). One can wonder whether one can take $m$ small, e.g., $m=2$? It seems we can't expect some universal $m$: In $\mathfrak{so}(n,1)$, if I'm correct the dimension of those $\mathbf{R}$-diagonalizable elements is $\le 2n$ and hence $m\ge (n+1)/4$.

Comment: This looks like exactly what I hoped for, but in the hard part (dealing with $\mathfrak{g}/J$ in the simple case) you use some terminology I am not familiar with.  Does "split quotient" just mean that the sequence $J \to \mathfrak{g} \to \mathfrak{g}/J$ splits (certainly $\mathfrak{g}/J$ is not $K$-split simple)? Also, do you have a reference for the fact that every simple $K$-isotropic subalgebra of $\mathfrak{gl}_n(K)$ contains a maximal $K$-split abelian subalgebra of $K$-diagonalizable element over general fields of characteristic 0?

Comment: For split: yes this is what I mean (yes split in this meaning is unrelated to $K$-split; in French it's 2 different words: scindé vs $K$-déployé). For the second: it's a trivial fact for an arbitrary subalgebra (just choose one of maximal dimension); what I use is that for a $K$-isotropic one it's positive-dimensional. But this is essentially the definition of $K$-isotropic.